# "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" running grab unit tests?

Tags: go

I'm interested in running the unit tests for the package https://github.com/cavaliercoder/grab in Go 1.13. Although my `GO111MODULE` environment is usually `on`, I've downloaded the package to my `GOPATH` using the following command:

```
env GO111MODULE=off go get -u -d github.com/cavaliercoder/grab
```

In the resuting `grab` directory, I've run `go mod init` which produces the following `go.mod`:

```
module github.com/cavaliercoder/grab

go 1.13
```

Now if I try to run `go test`, I get the following error:

```
> go test
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x12cc70d]

goroutine 1556 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc00010ea00)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:874 +0x3a3
panic(0x132ba20, 0x1629ed0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b2
github.com/cavaliercoder/grab.guessFilename(0xc00052aed0, 0xc0000aa008, 0x13951b5, 0x3, 0x139c440)
    /Users/kurt/go/src/github.com/cavaliercoder/grab/util.go:51 +0x2d
github.com/cavaliercoder/grab.TestURLFilenames.func2(0xc00010ea00)
    /Users/kurt/go/src/github.com/cavaliercoder/grab/util_test.go:54 +0x123
testing.tRunner(0xc00010ea00, 0x13afdf8)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:909 +0xc9
created by testing.(*T).Run
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:960 +0x350
exit status 2
FAIL    github.com/cavaliercoder/grab   2.531s
```

I've had a look at the offending test file, `util_test.go`, but couldn't find anything wrong with it:

```
package grab

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "testing"
)

func TestURLFilenames(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Valid", func(t *testing.T) {
        expect := "filename"
        testCases := []string{
            "http://test.com/filename",
            "http://test.com/path/filename",
            "http://test.com/deep/path/filename",
            "http://test.com/filename?with=args",
            "http://test.com/filename#with-fragment",
            "http://test.com/filename?with=args&and#with-fragment",
        }

        for _, tc := range testCases {
            req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", tc, nil)
            resp := &http.Response{
                Request: req,
            }
            actual, err := guessFilename(resp)
            if err != nil {
                t.Errorf("%v", err)
            }

            if actual != expect {
                t.Errorf("expected '%v', got '%v'", expect, actual)
            }
        }
    })

    t.Run("Invalid", func(t *testing.T) {
        testCases := []string{
            "http://test.com",
            "http://test.com/",
            "http://test.com/filename/",
            "http://test.com/filename/?with=args",
            "http://test.com/filename/#with-fragment",
            "http://test.com/filename\x00",
        }

        for _, tc := range testCases {
            req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", tc, nil)
            resp := &http.Response{
                Request: req,
            }

            _, err := guessFilename(resp)
            if err != ErrNoFilename {
                t.Errorf("expected '%v', got '%v'", ErrNoFilename, err)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The error message seems to be saying that `req` is a null pointer, but since it's defined using `http.NewRequest()` I don't see how that can be the case?

Comment: `http.NewRequest` returns two values: a request, and an error. If the returned error is not nil, the request value _is_ nil. (See actual implementation [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=28198:28299#L828).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this err print:

```
            req, err1 := http.NewRequest("GET", tc, nil)
            if err1 != nil {
                log.Println(err1.Error())
            }
```

It would print:

> parse http://test.com/filename: net/url: invalid control character in URL

which means this url `"http://test.com/filename\x00"` is not allowed.

Comment this line then it works:

```
[p1gd0g@p1gd0g-pc grab]$ go test
PASS
ok      github.com/cavaliercoder/grab   2.586s
```

Comment: In particular the [`guessFilename` function](https://github.com/cavaliercoder/grab/blob/228f991ef22e03a6e6454847f36e3fd17facabf7/util.go#L46-L69) is not happy when called with an errored response (because the `req` inside it is nil, presumably).